# XSLT matches() function not found

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am writing an XSLT transformation in which I wish to use the matches function to do a regex match and replace.

Visual Studio 2008 that 'matches ()' is an unknown XSLT function.

```
<xsl:when test="matches(normalize-space(.),'^([(]I[)])(.+)')">
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="^^([(]I[)])(.+)"
                        flags="x">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:variable name="paraNumber">
                                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="text">
                                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <span class="upper-I-double-bracket">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$paraNumber"/>
                            </span>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:when>
```

Comment: `matches()` is supported from XSLT 2.0 onwards. Windows' default XSLT parser only supports version 1.0 of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio (all currently known versions) uses the .NET XSLT 1.0 processor XslCompiledTransform or (versions before VS2005) the older XslTransform. These are XSLT 1.0 processors.

The `xsl:analyze-string` is only supported by XSLT 2.0+ and this explains the error message you get.

If you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor in a .NET environment you can choose either one of the Saxon.NET or XQSharp XSLT 2.0 processors that are developed especially for .NET.